# Weighting object values and determining a winner

Tags: javascript, json

I am attempting to weight the answers of a multiple choice quiz and calculate the winner.  In the below JSON, selecting the answer `A` twice will get you 4 "points".

How do I iterate through all the answers, and tally them up with their respective weightings taken into account?  I understand the logic behind determining a winner, but simply tallying the values is tripping me up.

The JSON structure is as follows:

```
{
    "questions": [
        {
            "answers": [
                {
                    "value": "A",
                    "weight": "1"
                },
                {
                    "value": "B",
                    "weight": "2"
                },
                {
                    "value": "C",
                    "weight": "3"
                },
                {
                    "value": "D",
                    "weight": "4"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "answers": [
                {
                    "value": "B",
                    "weight": "4"
                },
                {
                    "value": "D",
                    "weight": "1"
                },
                {
                    "value": "A",
                    "weight": "3"
                },
                {
                    "value": "C",
                    "weight": "2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the answers and the sum of their corresponding weights using the below function. Where data is the object in question. Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HectorBarbossa/j74g8j1g/).

```
var out = {};
data.questions.forEach(function(ans) {
    ans.answers.forEach(function(indv) {
        out[indv.value] = (out[indv.value] || 0) + parseInt(indv.weight, 10);
    });
});
console.log(out);
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly.  Thank you for such elegant code.

Answer (score 1):

The example below should work

```
var library = {
    "questions": [
        {
            "answers": [
                {
                    "value": "A",
                    "weight": "1"
                },
                {
                    "value": "B",
                    "weight": "2"
                },
                {
                    "value": "C",
                    "weight": "3"
                },
                {
                    "value": "D",
                    "weight": "4"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "answers": [
                {
                    "value": "B",
                    "weight": "4"
                },
                {
                    "value": "D",
                    "weight": "1"
                },
                {
                    "value": "A",
                    "weight": "3"
                },
                {
                    "value": "C",
                    "weight": "2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};


//Some test user answers, can change these to test other answers
var answers = ['B', 'C'];

//initialize total score
var score = 0;

//loop through each user answer
answers.forEach(function(answer, index) {

    //look at the answer in the question library at the same index as 
    //the user answer, and find the answer in that array with value 
    //that  equals user answer, then access the weight of that object, 
    //cast to number, and add to score
    score += Number(library.questions[index].answers.find(function(question) { return question.value === answer }).weight)
});

//score should print 4 if user answers are "B" and "C"
console.log(score);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I wanted the values to correspond to their weights -- not be mixed and matched. Perhaps I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Run the example below and read the comments for an explanation.

```js
function sumObjectArray(a) {
  //use reduce to iterate the array and keep a running total
  return a.reduce(function(prev, current) {
    //prev is previous result, or the empty object passed as a default
    //loop through all the items in current
    current.answers.forEach(function(item) {
      var value = item.value;
      var weight = Number(item.weight); //must convert to number to prevent string concatenation

      //if value is defined then add to it, otherwise set value to current value
      if (prev[value])
        prev[value] += weight;
      else
        prev[value] = weight;
    });

    //return updated object for next iteration through reduce()
    return prev;
  }, {}); //pass empty object as default value for prev
}

var input = [{
  "answers": [{
    "value": "A",
    "weight": "1"
  }, {
    "value": "B",
    "weight": "2"
  }, {
    "value": "C",
    "weight": "3"
  }, {
    "value": "D",
    "weight": "4"
  }]
}, {
  "answers": [{
    "value": "B",
    "weight": "4"
  }, {
    "value": "D",
    "weight": "1"
  }, {
    "value": "A",
    "weight": "3"
  }, {
    "value": "C",
    "weight": "2"
  }]
}]

console.log(sumObjectArray(input));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are tracking the user's answer through a list called `userAnswer`. What you can do is to use the `reduce` api on the `problem` variable (your questions), to come out with an overall score.

Within the `reduce` call, you can also use the `find` api to locate the answer object within it. Once you got the answer object all you have to do is to cast the weightage value in String to a `Number`, and add it to the accumulator parameter for `reduce`.

**Example:**

```
var userAnswer = [ "A", "A" ];
var problem = {
    "questions": [
    {
        "answers": [
            {
                "value": "A",
                "weight": "1"
            },
            {
                "value": "B",
                "weight": "2"
            },
            {
                "value": "C",
                "weight": "3"
            },
            {
                "value": "D",
                "weight": "4"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "answers": [
            {
                "value": "B",
                "weight": "4"
            },
            {
                "value": "D",
                "weight": "1"
            },
            {
                "value": "A",
                "weight": "3"
            },
            {
                "value": "C",
                "weight": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
};

let score = problem.questions.reduce((accumulator, question, index) => {
    let score = question.answers.find((answer) => { return (answer.value === userAnswer[index]); });
    return accumulator += Number(score.weight);
}, 0);

console.log(`Total score ${score}`);
```

**Output:**

> Total score 4

If you are keen, you may refer to more usage examples for `reduce` and `find` here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce